# I have some index of elements and i have another list same length how i add same index of first element to third index in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say,

I have one list:

```
List indexes = [3,1,2];
```

I have another list like:

```
List names = ["Sam","Tom","Max"]
```

And i have a alos a third list which one is empty list:

```
List nameIndex = [];
```

I have a button when i click on Button so i need to add names like first list which contains indexes. I need to set names like index position.

Ex: I need output like this:

```
print(nameIndex); //["Max","Sam","Tom"]
```

I have one twist too...

Let's say i have indexes like this:
[3,1]

Ex: I need output like this:

```
print(nameIndex); //["Max","Sam"]
```

How i can achieve this in Flutter??

Comment: Did you try doing it yourself?  It should be fairly straightforward to iterate over `indexes`, use each value (minus 1) to index into `names`, and then build a new `List` with the results.

Comment: Thanks  jamesdlin for your valuable answer :} It's help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

As per @jamesdlin comment

```
List indexes = [3,1,2];

List names = ["Sam","Tom","Max"];
```

On Button click:

```
List nameIndex = [];

for(var item in indexes)
    nameIndex.add(names[item-1]);
  
  print(nameIndex);
```

Comment: I have one twist and also i edit the question..

Comment: I appreciate your answer Niladri

Comment: Let's say i have index like this [0,1] then it's cause error

Comment: keep names[item-1] if you decide to go with array index position. Change to  names[item] if you go with array count.